# Wildcard SSL on ACM but doesn't work on subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

*.example.com, example.com, www.example.com - SSL - Issued by Amazon.

SSL installed and setup with ELB. Accessing the domain via example.com and www.example.com works with SSL perfectly. Yet when any sub domain(Subdomain.example.com) is accessed, SSL fails.

Subdomains are generated via a route.php script. Subdomains are dynamic.

Forcing SSl doesn't work. Tried other methods via .htaccess and its failing.

Does ELB work with wildcard SSL ?  How do i fix these problem?

Thanks

Comment: I found the solution. 

Add *.example.com to ElB with A record alias in route 53.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Add *.example.com to ElB with A record alias in route 53.